# Parallel coordinates multidimensional data not visualised in D3

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I am working on a parallel coordinates graph with `d3.js` and I am trying to plot some multiple dimensional data from an external `json` file.

This is how the data in the json file is structured:

```
[
{
"timestamp": 1437571117.035159, 
"dimension": 10, 
"value": [
  {
    "value": 0.13347661474528993, 
    "label": "A"
  }, 
  {
    "value": 0.8677079004784608, 
    "label": "B"
  }, 
  {
    "value": 0.7757451827314333, 
    "label": "C"
  }, 
  {
    "value": 0.9614725817942508, 
    "label": "D"
  }, 
  {
    "value": 0.5259754037241577, 
    "label": "E"
  } 
  {
    "value": 0.9683208234943124, 
    "label": "F"
  }, 
  {
    "value": 0.9256394748794468, 
    "label": "G"
  }, 
  {
    "value": 0.8749624261426282, 
    "label": "H"
  }, 
  {
    "value": 0.6171642160674041, 
    "label": "I"
  }, 
  {
    "value": 0.9933299503850428, 
    "label": "J"
  }
  ]
}
]
```

And this is how so far I am handling the domain and how the graph plots the items data:

```
d3.json("json/10dim.json", function(error, data) {

        if (error) {return console.log(error)};

        x.domain(dimensions = d3.keys(data[2].value).filter(function(d) {
            return y[d] = d3.scale.linear()
                                  .domain(d3.extent(data, function(p) { return +p[d]; }))
                                  .range([height, 0]);
        }));
etc...
```

The console does not give me any type of error, but neither the graphs get plotted, nor the axes are properly labeled. 
This is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xpka3om1/) with the complete code and this is the [reference](http://bl.ocks.org/jasondavies/1341281) that I have used to code this project.

Do you have an idea of how to solve this issue? In any case, thanks in advance for your replies!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I bet I know why you weren't seeing any error or HTML:  the code was being ran before the DOM loaded, i.e. the `<script>` tag your code was in was before the `<body>` tags.  In any case, you would have had an error off the bat since your JSON is not valid, but I assume that was a small example and the real JSON is valid.  Moving on, your JSON structure is very annoying to work with for this application.  Assuming you can't modify your JSON, I propose you read it in like you provided and then transform it a small bit to the following format:

```
[
    {
        "timestamp": 1437571117.035159, 
        "dimension": 10, 
        "A": 0.13347661474528993, 
        "B": 0.8677079004784608, 
        "C": 0.7757451827314333, 
        "D": 0.9614725817942508, 
        "E": 0.5259754037241577, 
        "F": 0.9683208234943124, 
        "G": 0.9256394748794468, 
        "H": 0.8749624261426282, 
        "I": 0.6171642160674041, 
        "J": 0.9933299503850428
    }
]
```

There are many good reasons as to why you would want to do this for this example, but mainly, the built-in D3 `data` methods want array of objects to read keys directly from.

If you do this, this full working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cntm2L4g/1/) should almost be a copy and paste for you.  A few notes from this fiddle:

- I did not load the JSON data from file;  instead, I just loaded it onto a variable so it would work with the jsfiddle.  To make the fiddle work for you, copy lines 74 and onward, and uncomment lines 93 and 169.
- I had to include another bogus entry in the data because it needs a min and a max to plot.  If you try using a single entry, you won't get an error; you'll just have a very uninteresting plot and no axes tick marks :-)
- Note that I included the `<body>` tag before the `<script>` tag that contains the JavaScript, else, it wouldn't work in the Fiddle for the same reason I gave above.

Lastly, make sure you add CSS before running the D3 code, else, you'll get a solid black graph!

Hope this helps!

Comment: It does help man! Thanks a lot! I know that the type of structure for the `json` is pretty annoying, but what I was trying to do is to be able to plot the graph no matter the type of file that I receive. I will investigate if there are ways to plot it with the structure I have, in case I can't the best is create a script to convert the json and give the best answer to you ;)

Comment: Glad it helped!  One comment:  unfortunately, there's no way to do that (plot an arbitrary data structure).  You need to explicitly tell D3 what the data format is, and even then, D3 isn't always flexible to plot any type of dataset, i.e. each D3 plot type assumes it's own "natural" data structure, and deviating even a bit from it can be pretty annoying, if not impossible, to implement.